# Creating a 2-level navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navbar, navigationbar

I would like to create a 2-level navigation with delay effect when hovering.

> in css Where to put `transition`?

here is the snippet code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&subset=latin-ext');
body {
  background: #ADAEAE;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background: #222122;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul a:hover {
  background-color: #404040;
  transition: all 1s;
}

nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
}

nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #222122;
}

nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dokument bez tytułu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Offer</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Offer2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Offer3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Offer4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please add some images of what you want and include the code you already have

Comment: OK, my appologise is first post on stackoverflow.

Comment: okay, so what do you want delayed?

Comment: I would like the list to come out with a delay. Such an animation effect

Comment: https://codepen.io/simplySam/pen/brrRMJ something like this?

Comment: like this https://kodilla.com/static/bootcamp/menu.gif

Comment: Do you chave any idea how make it?

Answer (score 0):

1. put `z-index:1;background: #222122;` on `nav ul a{}` to raise the link and hide the hidden menu below
2. in `nav li ul{}` remove `display: none;` and align the bottoms by `bottom:0;` and hide it under the a element with `z-index:-1;`
3. finally in `nav li:hover ul{}` have it move down with `bottom:-300%;` and add the animation here, you get a slide effect with `transition: bottom .2s;` and the ease-in makes it look like it hits something on the bottom

Note: bottom: -300% is because there are 3 items.

Note: transition is places under the `:hover` tag so that it disappears when you leave with your cursor, move it to `nav li ul` to make it slide back up

you can test in this snippet if that is indeed what you wanted.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&subset=latin-ext');
body {
  background: #ADAEAE;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background: #222122;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index:1;
  background: #222122;
}

nav ul a:hover {
  background-color: #404040;
  transition: all 1s;
}

nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
}

nav li ul {
  bottom:0;
  
  position: absolute;
  background: #222122;
  z-index:-1;
}

nav li:hover ul {
  bottom: -300%;
  display: block;
  transition: bottom .2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Offer</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Offer2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Offer3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Offer4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```